# Refreshing client browser window after new build is pushed on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, browser

We are using ExtJs 4.1 along with ASP.NET MVC. We release some updates or features after every 2-3 weeks. Most of the users don't close their browsers windows and hence use the old JavaScript. What options we have to forcefully refreshed client browser window.

Please note: I am not facing any caching issue here. And since the UI is developed using JavaScript framework, there is no post pack (or post-backs are async).

I don't think adding version to JS file will help my cause.

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?version=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see following options:

1. The easiest way is to add client side script which will periodically check version of your web page.
2. Of course you can build more complicated solution for example using SingnalR, in which you could push such method to client.
3. And the last one: store such version in session cookie or add custom header. Verify it on every request.